# How would a website know you're using selenium?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, automation, webdriver

I"m just curious if Selenium "identifies" itself. This is besides easy-to-detect practices such as clicking before the page is loaded, 5 seconds between every click, etc. I'm wondering if there is an inherent property.

According to the [WebDriver spec](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html) I found word of this interface (which may be the answer), but I don't seem to see any similar interface in the source code for Selenium etc.

> 4. Interface
>
>    partial interface Navigator {
>
>    > ```
>    >    readonly attribute boolean webdriver;
>    > ```
>    >
>    > };
>
> The webdriver IDL attribute of the Navigator interface must return the value of the webdriver-active flag, which is initially false.
>
> This property allows websites to determine that the user agent is under control by WebDriver, and can be used to help mitigate denial-of-service attacks.

Comment: I don't know what Selenium is, but if it's a headless browser or something similar, it might have a user-agent.

Comment: I am not sure that defending against selemium will help you very much.  Any average programmer with a c compiler and socket IO can send HTTP requests to your service and send which ever header information they want.  They can send AJAX requests, you name it.  It gets a little harder with https, but not a lot.

Comment: Web site could know so much about the current user from browser,OS,Screen Size, Ip, and so on.